# Capture a specified area of screen using java

Tags: java, jsf-2, screenshot

I am implementing a screenshot capture in my Java web Application Which Is Already Working. I however have an issue with the screenshot because the Image is Taken for the entire Screen:
[image]

As you can see this is the entire screen, I just want to capture the area with the graphs(the White area). The Code I am using to capture this screen is:

```
public void captureGraphs() {

        try {
            Dimension size = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            BufferedImage img = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(size));
            File f = new File("C:/capture");
            if (!f.exists()) {
                f.mkdir();
            }
            File[] flist = f.listFiles();
            for (File flist1 : flist) {
                flist1.delete();
            }
            ImageIO.write(img, "JPG", new File("C:/capture/screenShot.jpg"));
            System.out.println("Capture Successfull");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(
                    null,
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                            "Successful!",
                            "You have successfully taken a snapshot. Thank You"));
        } catch (HeadlessException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Is there any way I can change this code to capture the Mid Part only holding the graphs??

Comment: I have never done this before. But I think you could look into whichever API you are using and see if it lets you set the area 
of capture (length X breadth). If thats possible, then you can 
use a mouse to draw a rectangle around the area to be captured and pass the l,b to your code. You will need to have mouse event listeners as well.

Comment: are you capturing the **SERVER** screen?? OMG